# telerik:RadTimePicker get only time using javascript

Tags: javascript, time, get, telerik

I have telerik:RadTimePicker control and I want to get the time using javascript. In telerik web site they have mentioned

```
    var picker = $find("<%=RadDateTimePicker1.ClientID%>");
    var view = picker.get_timeView();
    alert(view.getTime());
```

But when I tried this I get all the details including time information.

```
    Tue Feb 26 2013 05:00:00 GMT+0530 (Sri Lanka Standard Time)
```

What I really need is `05:00:00`
Any easy way ?

Comment: Please don't include "Thanks everyone." in your question. It is useless noise.

Answer (score 0):

the getTime() is returning you a JavaScript Date object. You will need to use the JavaScript Date constructs to extract the Hours:Minutes:Seconds kind of data. Here is a link to JavaScript date documentation: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

you can just use the get_selectedDate() on the picker. This method too returns you a javaScript Date object. You can then extract the hours, minutes, seconds from the date object. we don't have any specific time string returning property on the picker object model.